# Elasticsearch: get up to date size of an index

Tags: elasticsearch

Q: How can I get the `size` of an index (using `_stats`), up-to-date since the last refresh?

I am doing some performance testing on an Elasticsearch cluster. The code is effectively:

```
Create INDEX
Set refresh_interval to -1 (don't refresh while inserting)
Insert 2000 documents into INDEX
Set refresh_interval back to 1 (default)

Force a refresh of INDEX
Get _stats of INDEX (particularly to get the size)
```

My understanding is that when the documents [are indexed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/near-real-time.html), they are first inserted into an ES in-memory buffer. Forcing a refresh will cause ES to create a Lucene segment for the documents still sitting in the buffer. (There are some various other cases in which the document buffer will empty into a Lucene segment, as well.)

I believe that [refreshing the index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/near-real-time.html#refresh-api) will guarantee documents up to that point to be searchable. I would expect the documents that ES makes searchable are also reflected in `_stats`. However, I find that the size from the stats request is non-deterministically inaccurate (e.g. it can be something like 520 Bytes instead of 23602).

I have tried sleeping my process after the refresh, before the `_stats` call, with varying success. But I'm wondering if there is a proper, consistent solution to get up-to-date stats? (Or instead if something in my understanding is incorrect).

**Example**

Immediately after inserting 2000 documents, I run `_stats` manually (repeatedly) in Sense and examine the results. For some amount of time, around 5 seconds, I will see this:

```
"primaries": {
  "docs": {
    "count": 2000,
    "deleted": 0
  },
  "store": {
    "size_in_bytes": 520,
    "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
```

Then (as ES suddenly becomes consistent with the recent changes), I'll see:

```
"primaries": {
  "docs": {
    "count": 2000,
    "deleted": 0
  },
  "store": {
    "size_in_bytes": 23602,
    "throttle_time_in_millis": 0
```

This result will persist indefinitely, as long as no new documents are added.

Comment: What makes you think that "that appears false"? Show us some numbers and what you expect instead.

Comment: Ah, right. I find the size of the index to be incorrect in the `_stats` call. I index 1000 documents (each of which contains a timestamp, a double, and a list of strings) with a `bulk` call. I call `refresh` on the index. Then I call `stats` on the index. The response shows the index is 130 Bytes in total. I can call `_stats` manually from Sense momentarily after, and see that there is now 135976 Bytes (Marvel also shows this larger, reasonable number on the Index summary page).

Comment: Can you show the list of commands you're running (i.e. your code)?

Comment: I can, but it's quite lengthy. More generally, though, I'm hoping to get some intuition on what ES is actually doing what I call `_stats`. I'll dig around some more, and get back ASAP.

Comment: I'm concerned about your refresh call, especially since you have a typo up there: `refresh_interal` should read `refresh_interval `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is related to `INDEX_STORE_STATS_REFRESH_INTERVAL_SETTING`, see https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/5.1/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/index/store/Store.java#L133-L134

It defaults to 10s, but you can change the value via `index.store.stats_refresh_interval`. I have no idea how much performance overhead this would introduce, so test this carefully if you consider changing the value.

This is also used for unit testing, see https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/5.1/core/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/index/store/StoreTests.java#L760

Comment: Thanks, nice find. So from a more generic perspective, I think this setting can be changed with something like:
```PUT /my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "index.store. stats_refresh_interval": 1
  }
}```

Comment: The setting should be a string with a time value, so creating an index with a 1 second stats refresh interval would be `PUT /my_index { "settings": { "index.store.stats_refresh_interval": "1s" } }`